# Exception with semaphore wxwidgets

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, wxwidgets

I'm using an example from WxWidget  [wiki](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Inter-Thread_and_Inter-Process_communication) to understand how to do the Inter-Thread and Inter-Process communication. I don't know why the example works but my code, very similar, doesn't at line "m_QueueCount.Wait(); // wait for semaphore (=queue count to become positive)"

When I run the code an exeption is showed:

> First-chance exception at 0x00B2DB61 in TeamTranslate.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0x00000078.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

and the breakpoint is at line 1749 of xstring file. This is the code:

```
size_type length() const _NOEXCEPT
        {   // return length of sequence
        return (this->_Mysize);
        }
```

I hope someone can tell me why this doesn't work!

Thank you in advance.

header:

```
class QueueMSG
{
public:
    QueueMSG(wxEvtHandler* pParent) : m_pParent(pParent) {}
    void AddJob(MessagePTR job); // push a job with given priority class onto the FIFO
    MessagePTR Pop();
    void Report(const Message::tCOMMANDS& cmd, MessagePTR arg); // report back to parent
    size_t Stacksize(); // helper function to return no of pending jobs

private:
    wxEvtHandler* m_pParent;
    std::vector<MessagePTR> m_Jobs; // multimap to reflect prioritization: values with lower keys come first, newer values with same key are appended
    wxMutex m_MutexQueue; // protects queue access
    wxSemaphore m_QueueCount; // semaphore count reflects number of queued jobs
};

class WorkerThread : public wxThread
{
public:
    WorkerThread(QueueMSG* pQueue) : m_pQueue(pQueue) { wxThread::Create(); }

private:
    QueueMSG* m_pQueue;
    BingTranslate bng;
    virtual wxThread::ExitCode Entry();
    virtual void OnJob();
}; // class WorkerThread : public wxThread
```

cpp:

```
void QueueMSG::AddJob(MessagePTR job) // push a job with given priority class onto the FIFO
{
    wxMutexLocker lock(m_MutexQueue); // lock the queue
    m_Jobs.push_back(job); // insert the prioritized entry into the multimap
    m_QueueCount.Post(); // new job has arrived: increment semaphore counter
} // void AddJob(const tJOB& job, const tPRIORITY& priority=eNORMAL)

MessagePTR QueueMSG::Pop()
{
    std::vector<MessagePTR>::iterator element;
    m_QueueCount.Wait(); // wait for semaphore (=queue count to become positive)
    m_MutexQueue.Lock(); // lock queue
    element = m_Jobs.begin(); // get the first entry from queue (higher priority classes come first)
    m_Jobs.erase(m_Jobs.begin()); // erase it
    m_MutexQueue.Unlock();// unlock queue
    return *element; // return job entry
} // tJOB Pop()

void QueueMSG::Report(const Message::tCOMMANDS& cmd, MessagePTR arg) // report back to parent
{
    wxThreadEvent evt(wxEVT_THREAD, wxID_ANY);// cmd); // create command event object
    evt.SetPayload<MessagePTR>(arg); // associate string with it
    wxQueueEvent(m_pParent, evt.Clone());
    //m_pParent->AddPendingEvent(evt); // and add it to parent's event queue
} // void Report(const tJOB::tCOMMANDS& cmd, const wxString& arg=wxEmptyString)

size_t QueueMSG::Stacksize()
{
    wxMutexLocker lock(m_MutexQueue); // lock queue until the size has been read
    return m_Jobs.size();
}

void WorkerThread::OnJob()
{
    MessagePTR job = m_pQueue->Pop(); // pop a job from the queue. this will block the worker thread if queue is empty
    bng.translateThis(job);
    switch (job->m_cmd)
    {
    case Message::eID_THREAD_EXIT: // thread should exit
        //Sleep(1000); // wait a while
        throw Message::eID_THREAD_EXIT; // confirm exit command
    case Message::eID_THREAD_JOB: // process a standard job
        //Sleep(2000);
        m_pQueue->Report(Message::eID_THREAD_JOB, job); // report successful completion
        break;
    case Message::eID_THREAD_JOBERR: // process a job that terminates with an error
        m_pQueue->Report(Message::eID_THREAD_JOB, job);
        //Sleep(1000);
        throw Message::eID_THREAD_EXIT; // report exit of worker thread
        break;
    case Message::eID_THREAD_NULL: // dummy command
    default: break; // default
    } // switch(job.m_cmd)
} // virtual void OnJob()    

wxThread::ExitCode WorkerThread::Entry()
{
    Message::tCOMMANDS iErr;
    m_pQueue->Report(Message::eID_THREAD_STARTED, NULL); // tell main thread that worker thread has successfully started
    try {
        while (true)
            OnJob();
    } // this is the main loop: process jobs until a job handler throws
    catch (Message::tCOMMANDS& i) {
        m_pQueue->Report(iErr = i, NULL);
    } // catch return value from error condition
    return (wxThread::ExitCode)iErr; // and return exit code
} // virtual wxThread::ExitCode Entry()
```

Message class:

```
#pragma once


#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wx/string.h>
#include <vector>

#include <memory>

enum MSGDirection{
    in,
    out
};

class Message {

public:
    enum tCOMMANDS // list of commands that are currently implemented
    {
        eID_THREAD_EXIT = wxID_EXIT, // thread should exit or wants to exit
        eID_THREAD_NULL = wxID_HIGHEST + 1, // dummy command
        eID_THREAD_STARTED, // worker thread has started OK
        eID_THREAD_JOB, // process normal job
        eID_THREAD_JOBERR // process errorneous job after which thread likes to exit
    }; // enum tCOMMANDS
    Message(MSGDirection dir, wxString from, wxString message, wxString language_org, wxString language_dest) : m_message(message), m_dir(dir), m_from(from), m_language_orig(language_org), m_language_dest(language_dest), m_cmd(eID_THREAD_EXIT){

        time_t          rawtime;
        struct tm*      timeinfo;
        char            timestamp[100];

        time(&rawtime);
        timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
        strftime(timestamp, 100, "%c", timeinfo);
        m_timestamp = timestamp;
    }
    Message() : m_cmd(eID_THREAD_NULL) {}

    ~Message(){ }

    void setIO(MSGDirection dir);
    MSGDirection getIO(){ return m_dir; };
    void setFrom(char* dir);
    wxString getFrom(){ return m_from; };

    void setMSG(wxString dir){
        m_message = dir;
    };
    wxString getMSG(){ return m_message; }
    wxString getTranslated(){ return m_translated; }
    wxString getTimeStamp(){ return m_timestamp; }
    wxString getLanguageOrig(){ return m_language_orig; }

    wxString getLanguageDest(){ return m_language_dest; }
    void  setSrtTranslate(wxString str){ m_translated = str; }
    tCOMMANDS m_cmd;
private:
    MSGDirection m_dir;
    wxString m_language_orig;
    wxString m_from;
    wxString m_message;
    wxString m_timestamp;
    wxString m_language_dest;
    wxString m_translated;

};


typedef std::shared_ptr<Message> MessagePTR;
typedef std::shared_ptr<std::vector<MessagePTR>> MessageQueuePTR;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `QueueMSG::Pop()` call, you use an iterator even after it has been invalidated. Even if it wasn't invalidated by your call to `erase` (which it will be, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Iterator_invalidation)), you cannot guarantee its validation after you have unlocked the mutex since you can be time-sliced at that point and then another thread can modify the container. Therefore you should instead do:

```
MessagePtr msg;
m_QueueCount.Wait();
{
    wxMutexLocker lock( m_MutexQueue );
    auto element = m_Jobs.begin();
    msg = *element;
    m_Jobs.erase(element);
}
return msg;
```

In their code - only slightly different than yours - they dereference the iterator to get a pair and return the contained second element via this line:

```
element=(m_Jobs.begin())->second; // that '->'
```

which is why they would not suffer from undefined behaviour.

Comment: You should prefer RAII objects like `wxMutexLocker` that will unlock the mutex when it is destroyed and after `element` has been dereferenced.

Comment: @Rollen I've used your code and I get the same exception :/

Comment: What is the data type of `MessagePtr`..and how is it created?

Comment: @Daniel976034, also have you looked at the stack frames to see what calls are made when the exception is thrown?

Comment: @RollenD'Souza 
`TeamTranslate.exe!std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >::size() Line 1749 C++`


_I'm going to add the code of message class__ DONE. I think the problem is with the semaphore. When I'm debbuging both projects, m_queueCount takes different values in each project. I mean, in the example I can see "m_semaphore 0x00000180 void *" but in my project, there's no "m_semaphore".